# Why I keep getting "Unfortunately, <App> has stopped" on my app? (java, android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-studio-2.1

I just wanted to make an app that calculates the percentage of a value, but I never succeeded. I kept trying different methods and different codes but none worked, but so far this is most legit looking one I've made. Anyway, when I compile the app and debug it, it has no error at all, but when I launched the app and try to click "calculate" the app instantly stops working and exits, and there is error always tells me "expected '('" on the second closing bracket and "expected';'" on the third closing bracket. can anybody see the problem with my code? I am newbie please help. Thank you, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the java code:
    package com.example.alexm.calc;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText percentedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentedit);
    final EditText valueedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueedit);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);


    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            int cal1, cal2, cal3, anser;
            String edit1 = percentedit.getText().toString();
            String edit2 = valueedit.getText().toString();
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(edit1);
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(edit2);
            cal1 = val1 * val2;
            cal2 = 100 * 1;
            cal3 = cal1/cal2;
            anser = cal3;


            result.setText(anser);



        }

    }
  }
}
```

here is the error

```
lc\MainActivity.java
Error:(52, 10) error: ')' expected
Error:(54, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Comment: You're missing a paren and a semicolon to close the `button.setOnClickListener()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

result.setText("" + anser);

`setText()` method do not accept `int` and that's probably why you are getting an error.

Btw, why do you have this line: `cal2 = 100 * 1;`?

Comment: it was a mistake sorry and what do you suggest i use? instead of setText?

Comment: @HellzYeahh You still could use setText, but you have to do it `.setText("" + anser);`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, replace this code into your code,

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){

        int cal1, cal2, cal3, anser;
        String edit1 = percentedit.getText().toString();
        String edit2 = valueedit.getText().toString();
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(edit1);
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(edit2);
        cal1 = val1 * val2;
        cal2 = 100 * 1;
        cal3 = cal1/cal2;
        anser = cal3;


        result.setText(anser);



    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket for setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
});

Just add in the `)`

The logs show you this by :
Error:(52, 10) error: ')' expected